# What is the mizraq (basin/bowl) used for in regards to the altar?

Tags: korban, mizbeach-altar

I understand every tool used in '[Exodus 27:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.27.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [38:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.38.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)' except for the 'basin'.

Was the basin used for burning grain offerings? Was the meat placed in the 'basin' or directly on the 'grille'? Was it used to boil the ram as in 'Exodus 29:31'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rashi [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.27.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.27.3.4&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) the basin was used to receive the blood of the sacrifices.**

> **ומזרקתיו**. לְקַבֵּל בָּהֶם דַּם הַזְּבָחִים

Artscroll explains the use of the utensils in [the verse](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.27.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) you are referring to

> After a sacrificial animal was slaughtered, its blood was accepted in
> basins, from which it was placed on the Altar. In order to properly
> burn the parts that were on the Altar, they were turned over and
> placed on the flames with forks. The incense that was placed twice a
> day on the Inner Altar had to be burned on coals that were taken from
> the Outer Altar. These glowing coals were taken on fire-pans.